# Cleaner Stops my AlarmManager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My `AlarmManager` works well but cleaner stops my `alarmManager` repeating task. or it not running my background service which extends `BroadcastReceiver` stops working.

I am starting `alarmManager` on click on button:

```
intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this,BroadCastReceiver1.class);

pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 30000 , pi);
```

In `BroadCastReceiver` Class I am putting `TOAST`. It works when cleaner are not performing... but when cleaner occurs my service got ended.
No `Toast` shows to me. What should I do to resolve this.

I declare in `Manifest file`:

```
<receiver android:name=".BroadCastReceiver1"
          android:exported="true"
          android:process=":remote">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter> </receiver>
```

Comment: adb shell am force-stop <packagename> 

stops everything, and AlarmManager wouldn't help.
Although, use _WAKEUP types of AlarmManager

Comment: RTC_WAKEUP is not worked because i want to upload some data in every 30 sec. but when i write RTC it upload data but RTC_wakeup dont.

Comment: Can I get Any Event When My AlarmManager stops? so that i can restart my service

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner stops the apps which are running their services in background just to save memory and cpu usage. You have to deselect your app from the running app list while boosting your device.

Comment: Programmatically it is possible that cleaner not affect my application?

Comment: How can it be possible that you run a service and it doesn't get noticed by the system? Even [AppLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock) stop working (service gets disabled until we restart applock by clicking on it.) when we run cleaner specially when we run CPU Cooler in the cleaner app.

Comment: Can I get any Event that say me that your service is disabled? by any reason whether by cleaner of system failure

Comment: @Nik I don't have much knowledge of Android, but if this would have been possible, it would have been used in apps like AppLock and UCBrowser (UC Music) which have billions of download.